# How to pass OFFSET and LIMIT to Function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have one problem which a little bit confusing me. I want to create function which will display all products and limit 20 products per page and OFFSET = (page - 1) * 20.
So far what I try to create something like this

```
FUNCTION TEST_FUNCTION(p_limit IN NUMBER,p_offset IN NUMBER)
    RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS 
    rc  SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
OPEN rc FOR   
     SELECT * FROM 
      (SELECT i.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM invoices) AS numberOfRows 
    FROM invoices i ORDER BY Id DESC)
    OFFSET = p_offset ROWS FETCH NEXT p_limit ROWS ONLY;         
RETURN rc;
END TEST_FUNCTION;
```

Here is problem which I get error

```
Error(125,12): PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

So I want to pass two variable in my function `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` but since I pass OFFSET I get error message.
So far I found a couple of answers here, but whatever I try I get error message, it seems like I couldn't pass OFFSET as variable.
Does anyone know any solution for this problem ?

Comment: You don't need the sub-queries and can use an analytic function instead. `SELECT i.*, COUNT(*) OVER() AS numberOfRows FROM invoices i ORDER BY Id DESC OFFSET p_offset ROWS FETCH NEXT p_limit ROWS ONLY`

Comment: @MT0 Thank you for suggestion. I solve problem. I notice this mistake :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not `offset = something`; remove `=`.

Then it kind of *does* something (on my sample table):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST_FUNCTION (p_limit   IN NUMBER,
  2                                            p_offset  IN NUMBER)
  3     RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
  4  IS
  5     rc  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  6  BEGIN
  7     OPEN rc FOR
  8        SELECT *
  9          FROM (  SELECT i.*, (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM emp) AS numberOfRows
 10                    FROM emp i
 11                ORDER BY empno DESC) OFFSET p_offset ROWS
 12         FETCH NEXT p_limit ROWS ONLY;
 13
 14     RETURN rc;
 15  END TEST_FUNCTION;
 16  /

Function created.

SQL> select test_function (1, 1) from dual;

TEST_FUNCTION(1,1)
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

     EMPNO ENAME NUMBEROFROWS
---------- ----- ------------
         1 King             2


SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for you help. I solve problem :) It works now :D